# How to fix "Value <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject" error in Android?

Tags: java, android, laravel

I try to send token to server side in my application in header. but when I try to send token I get this error

```
org.json.JSONException: Value <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

my server side is laravel.

Even I tried using `utf-8` but it didn't work

```
con.addRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + token+"; charset=utf-8" );
```

this is my code when I connect to server

```
@Override
protected Object doInBackground(Object[] objects) {

    try {
        URL url = new URL(objects[URL_ADDRESS].toString());
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod(objects[CONNECTION_METHOD].toString());

        if (token != null) {
            con.addRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + token+"; charset=utf-8" );
        }

        if (objects[CONNECTION_METHOD].toString().equals("POST")) {
            con.addRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
            con.setDoInput(true);
            con.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStream out = con.getOutputStream();
            out.write(objects[OUTPUT_OBJECT].toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));
        }

        String str;
        if (con.getResponseCode() < HttpURLConnection.HTTP_BAD_REQUEST) {
            str = getRespons(con.getInputStream()) /*+ jsRespons*/;
        } else {
            str = getRespons(con.getErrorStream()) /*+ jsRespons*/;
        }

        ///

        Map<String, List<String>> headerFields = con.getHeaderFields();

        Set<String> headerFieldsSet = headerFields.keySet();
        Iterator<String> hearerFieldsIter = headerFieldsSet.iterator();

        while (hearerFieldsIter.hasNext()) {

        String headerFieldKey = hearerFieldsIter.next();
        List<String> headerFieldValue = headerFields.get(headerFieldKey);

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (String value : headerFieldValue) {
            sb.append(value);
            sb.append("");
        }
            System.out.println(headerFieldKey + "=" + sb.toString() );
        }

        ///

        JSONObject jsResponse = new JSONObject(str);
        jsResponse.put("resMsg", con.getResponseMessage());
        jsResponse.put("response", con.getResponseCode());

        return jsResponse.toString();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        return e.toString();
    }

}
```

thanks.

Comment: Your server is sending back HTML or XML instead of JSON. You will need to look at that response text and see it gives you any ideas of why your server is doing that.

Comment: How could I see the response text? in Android I just get the error @CommonsWare

Comment: Um, `str` would seem to contain what you are trying to parse as JSON. Look at the contents of `str`.

Comment: No, It was not. @CommonsWare

Answer (score 0):

Add `Accept: application/json` header to your request according to the [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/passport#passing-the-access-token).

```java
con.addRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
```